# Cypress, TypeError: Enviromental variable 'undefined' outside of spec in headless mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

Situation is:

I have a bunch of cypress test spec that are depending on each other (the specification of tested project makes it impossibly to make them independent).

In the first spec I'm creating an array of objects and making it an environmental variable so I can operate on that array in other specs.

In head-full mode with the cypress UI dashboard it works pretty smoothly, but in headless mode the value of environmental variable created in one spec is 'undefined' in the next spec.

So

```
spec1.cy.ts

const arrafOfObjects = pageObject.functionThatReturnsTheArray();

Cypress.env("arrafOfObjects", arrafOfObjects);
```

```
spec2.cy.ts

const arrafOfObjects = Cypress.env("arrafOfObjects");

const length = arrafOfObjects.length //TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

```
cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');
const { removeDirectory } = require('cypress-delete-downloads-folder');

const env = 'staging' 

module.exports = defineConfig({

  env:{
    godUser: 'some.user@domain.cloud',
    passwordChargeGodUser: 'secretPassword'
    securityconfigHash: process.env.secretConfigHash
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'https://url.' + env + '.domain.cloud',
    excludeSpecPattern : ["cypress/e2e/2-advanced-examples","cypress/e2e/1-getting-started", "cypress/e2e/0-financeportal"],
    downloadsFolder: "cypress/downloads",
    testIsolation: false,
    trashAssetsBeforeRuns : true,
    experimentalRunAllSpecs : true,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
    experimentalOriginDependencies: false,
    
    defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
    numTestsKeptInMemory : 0,
    requestTimeout : 30000,
    responseTimeout : 50000,
    pageLoadTimeout: 1000000, 
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks);
      on('task', { removeDirectory })
    },
  },

});
```

EDIT: I did some more investigation and it seems that headless mode is ignoring `testIsolation: false` configuration and is wiping out memory... any idea how it's possible?

Answer (score 6):

`experimentalRunAllSpecs` creates one spec in GUI/"Run all specs" - called "All specs" - which is why `Cypress.env()` is not cleared for this type of run.

`cypress run` creates a child process for each spec, so `Cypress.env()` is not preserved. (Part of the purpose of this is enabling parallel running)

You can create a "controlling" spec that imports the other specs, you should find the `Cypress.env()` is preserved in that same way as `experimentalRunAllSpecs`.

**spec1.cy.js**

```js
it('spec1 test', () => {
  Cypress.env('my-array', [1,2,3])
})
```

**spec2.cy.js**

```js
it('spec2 test', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('my-array')).to.deep.eq([1,2,3])  // passing in headless mode
})
```

**spec3.cy.js**

`yarn cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/spec3.cy.js`

```js
require('./spec1.cy.js')
require('./spec2.cy.js')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can transfer data between specs with a couple of tasks, storing the data in Cypress Node process which is not affected by cleardown.

The tasks are

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const data = {}   // data to transfer between specs goes here

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        save({key, value}) {
          data[key] = value
          return data
        },
        load(key) {
          return data[key] || null
        },
      })
    },
```

Since you have page objects, you will have to apply the data at the top of each spec, in a `before()`.

Each spec will inherit it's data from the previous spec.

As an example, if I have a simple Rectangle class that saves height and width and calculates area (this represents the page object class)

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;        // class data can be saved between tests
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Method
  area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

**spec1.cy.js**

```js
it('setting some page object data', () => {

  const rectangle = new Rectangle(10,10)
  expect(rectangle.area()).to.eq(100)       // height * width

  // save data to task
  cy.task('save', {key: 'rect', value: rectangle})
})
```

**spec2.cy.js**

```js
let rectangle

before(() => {
  cy.task('load', 'rect').then(data => {
    rectangle = new Rectangle()           
    Object.assign(rectangle, data)        // add saved data to this PO
  })
})

it('using data session in another spec', () => {
  expect(rectangle.area()).to.eq(100)             // passes
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The plugin [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session?tab=readme-ov-file#shareacrossspecs) has an option ***shareAcrossSpecs*** that seems to work for your scenario.

This is an example, since you have pageObjects I added a property that is a function (in case serialization breaks functions)

**spec1.cy.js**

```js
before(() => {
  const arrayOfObjects = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c': () => 3}]
  cy.dataSession({
    name: 'common', // data name
    setup: () => arrayOfObjects, // data creation commands
    shareAcrossSpecs: true,
  })
})

it('setting data session', () => {
  expect(Cypress.getDataSession('common')[0].a).to.equal(1)
  expect(Cypress.getDataSession('common')[2].c()).to.equal(3)
})
```

**spec2.cy.js**

```js
it('using data session in another spec', () => {
  expect(Cypress.getDataSession('common')[0].a).to.equal(1)
  expect(Cypress.getDataSession('common')[2].c()).to.equal(3)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Cypress.env` variables are reset in each spec file.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env) Headed mode may be doing something wonky or different than I'd expect, but it makes sense that the environment variable is undefined in the new spec file. My recommendation is to re-structure your setup so that your spec files aren't dependent on one another - there are no assurances that your files will always run in a specific order, and it is generally best practice to have each test be as independent as possible.

> Environment variables set using Cypress.env are only in scope for the current spec file.

> Cypress runs each spec file in isolation: the browser is exited between specs. Environment variables added or changed in one spec won't be visible in other specs.

Comment: I absolutely agree on that, dependent tests are unstable and it's a pain to debug them. But the core functionality of tested app is passing and modyfying the same set of data on each step, and because I need to make data randomised on step one (hardcoded values are not a good practice as well), every next step needs to know the state of the data from the previous one. I could keep all the test in separate `it("", () => { }})` but it is also not a good idea. Is it technically impossible to disabled test isolation on the headless mode?